# How does the Favored Enemy feature of the Slayer prestige class work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, stacking

I am building a Ranger 4/ Slayer 7/Ardent 2 NPC. Now I wonder about the interaction of the Slayer's and the Ranger's Favored Enemy class feature:

The NPC is themed to hate Yuan-Ti, so he got humanoid (reptilian) as his ranger class favored enemy.

The  [Slayer](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/prestigeClasses/slayer.htm) class demands  "a type of psionic creature" as the enemy he detests most.

I am not sure what "type" means in this context: A specific monster (like Yuan-Ti - I am using the psionic version in my campaign) or the types of favored enemies of the ranger with "psionic" added (like psionic reptilian humanoids). Either way I am uncertain whether the bonus of the two favored enemy class features would stack.

So these are my two questions: How specific does the Slayers favored enemy have to be and does the class features bonus stack with the same class feature of the ranger?

Comment: Your two questions seem very different to me. You should edit one of them out of this post and ask it separately.

Comment: I think the two questions are closely related, because the stacking rules say that a bonus does not stack with itself. I think it is difficult to answer the second question without the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A single psionic race

The original version of the Slayer class was the Illithid Slayer. The class focused on the illithid race in the same fashion as a ranger's Favored Enemy ability focused on a type of creature.

Due to the term Illithid being considered non OGL property, the SRD removed the term Illithid from the class, and generalized the class.

Much like humanoids had to be broken down into specific sub groups for the ranger's ability, the generic Slayer should pick a psionic sub group, or in other words, a psionic race.

The use of the term *type* is probably an unfortunate grammar choice, or perhaps simply copied from the ranger ability.

---

I believe the bonus from favored enemy is untyped, however the text from the ranger version states:

> If a specific creature falls into more than one category of favored enemy (for instance, devils are both evil outsiders and lawful outsiders), the ranger’s bonuses do not stack; he simply uses
> whichever bonus is higher. See the Monster Manual for more information on types of creatures.

... thus as a DM, I would lean towards not stacking in any case.

Comment: Thank you! Espescially for the stacking rule - I entirely missed that!

Comment: You are most welcome!